# Error 25 when creating a service-based database/SQL server database inside Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Using Visual Studio Community 2015 and SQL Server Enterprise 2014.
I have been trying to find a solution for this since yesterday. I'm getting this error message:

Network-related or instance-specific error. Error 25 - Connection string is not valid.

Here is my connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="LocalSql" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;User ID=Administrator;Password=***********;User Instance=False"/>
```

I can connect to the server from Visual Studio (through Data Connections and SQL Server Object Explorer). I can also connect to the server using SQL Server Mgmt Console.

Remote connections allowed. In Visual Studio Tool>Data Connections: Sql Server instance name is MSSQLSERVER.

I even enabled all transport protocols. TCP, Named Pipes, Shared Memory. All client protocols are also enabled.

SQL Server is running alongside Visual Studio when I attempt to create the service-based database/Sql server database from Solution Explorer.

Has anyone got this working with this setup? Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server 2014 are both running from the same computer. Or is this one of those broken software interfaces that we should just ignore?

As always, your time is much appreciated.

Comment: You say your instance is named: `MSSQLSERVER` -- why are you specifying `Data Source=SERVER` in your connection string?

Comment: @David that connection string is copied from the properties of the server inside Visual Studio. It is not a named instance. I think I saw somewhere that you put that in Visual Studio tools, because that is the default name of SQL server. I checked it in services as well and MSSQLSERVER is indeed the default name.

Answer (score 0):

In your connection string do specify the SQL Server instance name if it's a named instance rather a default instance. Also, specify the initial database name to connect to like below along with the `Provider Name`

```
connectionString="Data Source=SERVER\instance_name;Database=Sample;User ID=Administrator;Password=***********;User Instance=False"; Provider="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: its not a named instance. Ok I will try to specify a database and provider

Comment: Tried it Rahul, still the same error. Funny thing is I can create a database from Data Connections in Visual Studio and it reflects in Sql Server Mgmt Console. I just can't create one from Solution Explorer: Service-based/Sql server database.